# Deploy app from Xcode without dev account

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, app-store, ionic4

I developed an app and I would like to deploy it in the way tutuapp, tweakbox, downloadable from an url.

I set up the .plist file, and I tried the technique to recover the archive on xcode by converting the .app to .ipa, only once it installs on the iphone application remain grayed out ...

I know that passing dev would be simpler but it's expensive 100 € for apps that I share just 2-3 people in my life.

I thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a different possibility.
If you „jailbreak“ the other iPhones it‘s possible to install your App on these other iPhones.